# Bulk crop images from CMD/PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, crop

Is there any CMDline utility or 3rd party app that can take each and every image 
 in a folder (screenshot in my case) and crop them all one by one to a particular resolution?

For instance, I have 3 monitors in extended view, and I sometimes need to take screenshots on the fly, and the most convenient way to do so, is with WinKey + PrtScrn combination. The downside is that I manually have to crop out 2 monitors afterwards for about 20-30 images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a light-weight tool that can be used for this. Here is an example that croppes all jpg images in a directory and puts the results in a new folder:

```
cd path/to/dir/
mogrify -crop +100+10 -quality 100 -path ../cropped *.jpg
```

Here, 100 pixels from the left border and 10 pixels from the top are removed. See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) for more information on how to use crop.

Comment: I have tried with ImageMagic, and indeed it gets the job, Nice job, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried XnCovert? XnConvert is free cross-platform batch image processor, allowing you to combine over 80 actions. Compatible with 500 formats. It uses the batch processing module of XnViewMP and it is freeware and you can donate them if you find it useful. https://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely give it a shot. I looks promising